# What is "Rotational Invariance" in the context of qubits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, symmetry

In [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/461032/partial-measurement-of-a-composite-state/461033?noredirect=1#comment1035130_461033) the state, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left|00\right\rangle +\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left|01\right\rangle +\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left|11\right\rangle$, has been said in the answers to not be able to collapse into $\frac{1}{2}|11\rangle \langle11| + \frac{1}{2}|00\rangle \langle00|$ after measuring a $|0\rangle$ in the first qubit because this would break "rotational invariance".

I understand mathematically that we project the state into $|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes1\!\!1$ and it becomes $|0\rangle\otimes(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$.

(Phrasing the question in a way suggested by the comments:) If I consider the situation in which a measurement the 1st qubit in the 0,1 basis causes the second qubit to collapses in the 0,1 basis - why would this break rotational invariance? (And is this method of evauluation a useful way of investigating measuring qubits in general?)

Comment: I'm a bit confused here as to whether or not this assertion is correct. $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ only has one $SU(2)$ invariant contraction, which is the singlet state $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|10\rangle - |01\rangle)$$

Comment: I just edited the question to mention that this collapse happens after observing a measurement of the state $|0 \rangle$ in the first qubit, if that clarifies things.

Comment: I think you would have to first propose a *general* rule before this can be answered.  Proposed general "rule": If I measure the 1st qubit in the 0,1 basis, the second qubit also collapses in the 0,1 basis.  Why does this break rotational invariance. Is this the question?

Comment: Note that in my original comment, I wrote "basis dependent", which is a better wording than "rotational invariance".

Comment: Thanks. I changed things around - maybe this will be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we are using the -- incorrect -- rule that upon measuring the first qubit in the $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$ basis and obtaining the $|0\rangle$ outcome, the second qubit collapses in the $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$ basis, i.e. on $|00\rangle$ and $|01\rangle$.

Our test state is 
$$
|\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left|00\right\rangle +\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left|01\right\rangle +\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left|11\right\rangle\ .
$$
By applying a Hadamard transformation to the second qubit, this becomes
$$
|\Phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left|00\right\rangle +\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left|10\right\rangle -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left|11\right\rangle\ .
$$
Now let's apply our rule: In the first case, we get
$|00\rangle$ and $|01\rangle$, each with probability $1/2$. In the second case, we get $|00\rangle$ with probability $1$ -- and if we undo the rotation, we get $|0\rangle(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ with unit probability, rather than the 50/50 mixture we got in the first case.

Thus, this scheme is not invariant under a basis transformation of the $B$ system -- depending in which basis I express my $B$ system (this is what the Hadamard does), I get different results.  So if you want a measurement scheme which gives the same result independent of the basis you choose for $B$, the proposed scheme does not work.